# Is latest Instruments not support A16 for CPU counters?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, instruments, xcode-instruments

I would like to check CPU counters by Instruments for A16 (iPhone 14 Pro Max, iOS 16.0, 16.3), but it shows
unsupported on 'Recording Options' -> 'CPU Name'. Anyone meet the same situation? or it is happened only for me?

I tried these versions of Instruments.
14.0 (14a5294e)
14.0 (14A309)
14.1 (14B5024i)
14.1 beta 3 (14B5033e)
14.1 RC (14B47)
14.1 RC2 (14B47b)
14.1 (14B47b)
14.1 (14C18)
14.3 beta (14E5197f)
14.3 beta 2 (14E5207e)
14.3 beta 3 (14E5215g)
14.3 RC (14E222a)
14.3 (14E222b)
14.3.1 (14E300c)
15 beta (15A5160n)
15 beta 3 (15A5195k)
15 beta 4 (15A5195m)
15 beta 6 (15A5219j)
15 beta 7 (15A5229h)
15 beta 8 (15A5229m)
15 RC (15A240d)

Comment: Same issue as: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/722814, you may want to submit a bug report to Apple.

Comment: Do you know how to submit a bug report to Apple?

Comment: Here it is: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can get CPU counter from A16 (iOS 16.6.1) and Xcode 15 (15A240d).

Not sure why Apple limited CPU counter information like this. It is almost 1 year after A16 release.

Comment: Your question lists that version of Xcode as still being an issue. Perhaps you should remove that last version from your question.

Comment: @HangarRash I forgot to modify it. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

CPU counter on A16/A17 devices with iOS17 and Xcode 15 (15A240d) is unsupported.

Comment: junjie1475 大大，沒想到會在這裡遇到你，你在 github 上的貢獻真的讓我收獲很多，先謝謝你 :D

A17 Pro device with iOS 17 is also not supported for me.
It is weird that A16 is not supported with iOS 17 but supported with iOS 16.6.1.

Comment: @BradChou 很高兴我可以帮助到你！