# Is latest Instruments not support A17 Pro for CPU counters?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, instruments, xcode-instruments

I would like to check CPU counters by Instruments for A17 Pro (iPhone 15 Pro, iOS 17.0), but it shows unsupported on 'Recording Options' -> 'CPU Name'. Anyone meet the same situation? or it is happened only for me?

I tried these versions of Instruments.
iOS 17.0

- 15.0 (15A240d)
  iOS 17.1
  15.0.1 (15A507)

Comment: Related post by OP: [Is latest Instruments not support A16 for CPU counters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73850209/is-latest-instruments-not-support-a16-for-cpu-counters?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C101.2694)

Answer (score 1):

starting with iOS 17 and Xcode 15, Xcode copies files from `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/CoreDeviceDDIs/iOS_DDI.dmg` to the device. This image doesn't include the CPU database, leading to Instruments.app reporting a lack of CPU support.

`kperfdata.framework` still works on iOS 17. So if you can copy the necessary files to either /usr/share/kpep/ or /usr/local/share/kpep/, Instruments.app should continue to work as expected. But the regular app doesn't have write access to these two folders. Hope Apple can fix it.

Here is a list of A17 pro's PMCs event-key that I extracted from XNU kernel build https://gist.github.com/junjie1475/897e2733a345d5a0bcff56e95c94c4bf.